# How to connect read only TextField with a custom keyboard?

Tags: flutter

How to connect read only TextField with a custom keyboard?

For now the input field defined like this, the default keyboard is not used

```
TextField(
   ...
   showCursor: true,
   readOnly: true,
   autocorrect: false,
)
```

How to display in TextField some variable and connect it with flashing cursor? I.e. I need to use a custom keyboard to input text and display it "with the feeling" of text field.

Comment: change `readOnly: false`

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada the default keyboard  should not be used